# How to get a value after a character, from a string based on a text match using formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, text-extraction

I got the following value:

```
tradicional;cropped$9$10;mullet$5$7
```

In cell `A1`, I can choose between `tradicional, cropped and mullet`. In cell `A2`, I pick `1`, or `2`.

If I pick `cropped` and 2, the value to be returned would be 10.

If I pick `mullet` and 1, the value to be returned would be 5.
If

I'd go for `len` and `left`, but I don't see how this is going to work using the matching criteria.

Here's a practical example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dFzXmtKj15EzApTKUKv8yF7_mAIB1COPSgMLMMmFE4E/edit?usp=sharing

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please share a link to a spreadsheet that contains 5 or 10 rows of *realistic data* that represents all possible scenarios that may turn up in this data. Will the there *always* be exactly three choices, and *always* these same three choices? What if someone chooses "tradicional" in A1 and 2 in A2? Will "tradicional" *sometimes* have values associated with it? As you can see, there are just too many unknown factors right now.

Comment: hi, @ErikTyler! Thanks for your input. If ```tradicional```, then 0. If I get the logic for this one, I'll be able to extend it to other variations. Thank you!

Comment: You haven't shared a link to a spreadsheet as I described above.

Comment: You're right, @ErikTyler! Just added a link to it above. Thanks.

Comment: I see that you shared a link. However, this one row of data isn't enough to explain your actual goal in practical use. In other words, I think you will be trying to do something with *many* lines of data this way; but it is not clear what the source data will be for each different row. Will *every* row reference the same string that is showing in E4 right now? If not, how are those Col-E strings being determined? I think this is what we call an "XY problem," meaning that what you are asking for in this small example probably won't fit your larger need. Can you provide more rows/details?

Comment: Also, it will help if you explain why that E4 string has to be that way. Why not just set up a separate sheet with it's and pricing, and then refer to that sheet instead of this string? Again, the "big picture" goal of what you are ultimately trying to do is not clear at all yet.

Comment: @ErikTyler, I'll populate one cell and I'll have that combined text as the result for the formula seeked to extract the price. So this is not going to be rows of data, but as represented in that example.

Comment: The database where I'll get that text from is set like that. Changing it would require a lot more work, than trying to extract the price like that... @ErikTyler. Very specific, I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comments to your original post, I feel that there is a lot we don't know about your bigger goal. But as you aren't able to provide that, this solution will work for your one exact example.

Place the following formula in C4:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4;SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(E4;";"));"$");B4+1;FALSE)))`

(See the new sheet "Erik Help.")

The inner `SPLIT` splits the E4 string at every semicolon.

`FLATTEN` sends that all to one column.

The outer `SPLIT` then splits at each "$".

`VLOOKUP` can then try to find the Col-A term in the first column of the resulting virtual chart. If found, it will return the column value that matches the Col-B value + 1 (since column 1 of the virtual array is the labels, e.g., 'tradicional,' etc.).

If no match is found for both the Col-A and Col-B data, then `IFERROR` returns null.

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you, and hopefully you can adapt it to your greater spreadsheet application.

Comment: Just did and it worked wonders! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

You can split the text string on semicolon ";" into 3 parts. The depending on which part you choose, you can split it on dollar sign "$" then you can get the "item" and return an integer.  I leave it to you to figure out how to incorporate into your script.

**Script (Test Case)**

```
function makeAChoice() {
  try {
    console.log("You chose "+getChoice("cropped",2));
    console.log("You chose "+getChoice("mullet",1));
    console.log("You chose "+getChoice("somethingelse",1));
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

function getChoice(choice,item) {
  try {
    var text = "tradicional;cropped$9$10;mullet$5$7";
    text = text.split(";");
    text = text.filter( s => s.includes(choice) );
    if( text.length < 1 ) throw "Error choice ["+choice+"] not found!";
    text = text[0].split("$");
    return parseInt(text[item]);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Console.log**

```
8:32:38 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:32:38 AM  Info    You chose 10
8:32:38 AM  Info    You chose 5
8:32:38 AM  Info    Error choice [somethingelse] not found!
8:32:38 AM  Info    You chose undefined
8:32:38 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: Hi! This is neat! Thank you! I'd have to create an onEdit function, since this will populate many cells based on the user's choice. I was thinking of a formula at first...If I don't get it sorted, I'll resort to your code above. Thanks a lot!